# Can 3rd-party develop Lockscreen app on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Can 3rd-party develop Lockscreen app on WP8.1, just like [Tetra Lockscreen](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/tetra-lockscreen/11076e3b-6a9e-46e5-a563-d1f6b32a5df3) or [Live Lock Screen BETA](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/live-lock-screen-beta/f5685f66-5e43-46f9-b95e-bfc2a4a15de3)? Is there have relevant tech documents I can follow?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571206(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to develop dynamic lockscreen apps like Tetra Lockscreen. Microsoft hasn't made the API for dynamic lockscreens public to developers yet unfortunately.